# Does it imply that $\int _0^\infty f_n\to \int _0^\infty f$?

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly .
>
> Does it imply that $\int _0^\infty f_n\to \int _0^\infty f$?

I think the answer is no though I could not find a counter-example.

Because if $f_n\to f$ uniformly then
$\int _0^\infty |f_n-  f|<\epsilon \times \infty $ which is undefined.

Comment: This should be true if you impose boundedness restrictions. Otherwise you run into issues with the absolute values of the difference when they are both infinite.

Comment: @David Boundedness is clearly not enough. Consider the sequence of  (uniformly bounded) functions $f_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}$.

We have $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty = \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}{0}$, yet $\int_0^\infty f_n =1 \not \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}{0}$.

Comment: @Clement C. Right, what if the set also has bounded measure. I should have been more specific in my comment. He didn't state that he was integrating w.r.t. the lebesgue measure. My comment meant bounded functions, and then bounded measure of the set. Then we have clearly,

$$
\left \vert \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f-f_n d\mu \right\vert \le \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \vert f_n - f \vert d\mu \le \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \varepsilon d\mu = \varepsilon \mu(\mathbb{R}_+)   
$$

for sufficiently large $n$. This, of course, only works if $\mu(\mathbb{R}_+)<\infty$

Comment: Although, rereading the last line of his question, the implication does seem to be that $\mu(\mathbb{R}_+)=\infty$ in the cases he is considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take a triangle and stretch it while maintaining its area.